# Run cucumber test in IE/VirtualBox

Tags: ruby, vagrant, cucumber, virtualbox

I run my cucumber tests from an Ubuntu VM (VirtualBox), host machine is Windows. What I would like to do is now run the same tests in different IE versions (again within VirtualBox).

So what i have done so far is use Vagrant to set my IE8 box up, giving myself a designated IP address and forwarding ports (or so I hope :-))

```
config.vm.network :forwarded_port, guest: 80, host: 8080
config.vm.network :private_network, ip: "192.168.33.100"
```

The box is setup successfully and now I'm a little stuck in the config in cucumber.

I run my tests against multiple environments, so my `APP_HOST` and a `BROWSER` gets passed on the command line

```
  Capybara.app_host = case ENV['ENV']
    when 'test'
      APP = 'http://test.myapp.co.uk'
    when 'qa'
      APP = 'http://qa.myapp.co.uk'           
  end

  Capybara.default_driver = case ENV['BROWSER']
    when 'chrome'
      :chrome 
   when 'ie8'
      :ie_8
   else
     fail 'Please choose one of the following: chrome, firefox, headless or IE. For example BROWSER=chrome'
   end
```

I have set up my driver config like so

```
Capybara.register_driver :ie_8 do |app|
  Capybara::Selenium::Driver.new(app,
    browser: :remote,
    url: 'http://192.168.33.100:80/wd/hub', # This is where I am unsure
   desired_capabilities: :internet_explorer)
end
```

So to run a test I do this `cucumber --tags @mytag BROWSER=ie8 ENV=test`

At the moment the url configuration to connect to my box is throwing me, I thought it was the ip address and port number of the box you wanted to connect to ?

When running this i get an error

```
**end of file reached (EOFError)**
```

Could anyone point me in the direction of where I am going wrong please

Thanks

Update

When doing `vagrant up` this is the output i get in the console

```
default: Adapter 1: nat
default: Adapter 2: hostonly
default: Adapter 3: bridged
default: Forwarding ports...
default: 80 => 8080 (adapter 1)
default: 5985 => 55985 (adapter 1)
default: 5986 => 55986 (adapter 1)
default: WinRM address: 127.0.0.1:55985
default: WinRM username: vagrant
default: WinRM transport: plaintext
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
config.vm.network :forwarded_port, guest: 80, host: 8080
```

means you forward the 80 port from the guest VM to the 8080 local port of your host.

in other word, if you want to access http://http://192.168.33.100:80 of the VM you will need to access http://192.168.33.100:8080 from your local host.

in your case replace

```
url: 'http://192.168.33.100:80/wd/hub'
```

by

```
url: 'http://192.168.33.100:8080/wd/hub'
```

Comment: thanks for clearing that up for me, im getting a connection timeout error, all i want to do is connect to my VM with IE, do i even need to specify a port? I think ive muddle myself up somewhere, Ive added some more info to my question